# How to run jmeter test in CircleCI?

Tags: jmeter, circleci

I have the following configurations set in my circle.yml file:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 6.11.1
dependencies:
  post:
    - sudo apt-get update
    - wget -c http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.2.zip
    - sudo apt-get install unzip
    - unzip apache-jmeter-3.2.zip
    - aws s3 cp s3://ci-test/CI_Test_jmt.jmx ~/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/CI_Test_jmt.jmx
    - cd apache-jmeter-3.2/bin
    - sh jmeter.sh -n -t CI_Test_jmt.jmx
```

I'm getting the following error:

> $ sh jmeter.sh -n -t CI_Test_jmt.jmx
>   sh: 0: Can't open jmeter.sh
>   
> sh jmeter.sh -n -t CI_Test_jmt.jmx returned exit code 127
>   
> Action failed: sh jmeter.sh -n -t CI_Test_jmt.jmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error found a temporary solution. 
The following is my new circle.yml configuration:

```
dependencies:
post:
    - aws s3 cp s3://ci-test/apache-jmeter-3.2/ ~ --recursive
    - cd bin/ && /bin/sh jmeter.sh -n -t CI_Test_jmt.jmx
```

**Step 1:** I copied my jmeter files from my local machine to S3 instance (this is because the apache's ftp server at times fails to respond)

**Step 2:** Copied my jmeter files from S3 to CircleCI

**Step 3:** Run the cmd: cd bin/ && /bin/sh jmeter.sh -n -t CI_Test_jmt.jmx

Any further tweaks in my above-written configuration would be highly appreciated. I don't know when I'm trying to copy the apache-jmeter-3.2 folder from S3 to CircleCI, it's getting copied to the /bin directory somehow instead of creating a folder by the name apache-jmeter-3.2 in the home directory of Circleci.